# Listings: new environments with arguments

Tags: listings, environments

I have this basic question. How can use arguments with `listings`? I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
\lstnewenvironment{cor}[2][] 
{\linerange{#1-#2},\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,,basicstyle=\scriptsize, 
 showspaces=false,showtabs=false,,breaklines=true,showstringspaces=false,
breakatwhitespace=true  }}
{}
```

and then I used it in the following way:

```
\begin{cor}{2}{3}
\end{cor}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{listings}    
\lstnewenvironment{X}[2]{%
    \lstset{language=[Sharp]C,linerange=#1-#2}}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{X}{1}{1}
 class A{static void Main(){}}
\end{X}
\end{document}
```

Comment: one more question i'm having serious problem understanding well the syntax of latex, i now a lot of programming languages but latex still it see for me a little cryptic, do you know what is the key to fully understand it?

Comment: @voodoomsr, you should create a new question in a new topic and not in this topic. This is the rule to avoid cluttering this site. :-)

Comment: @xport, ok im gonna creating right away

Comment: @xport: It's great that you asked voodoomsr to ask a new question. It worked! However, please do try and post _minimal_ examples and _short_ screenshots. Moreover, usually one should [wait a day](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/209/1235) before accepting an answer, so you should wait with such comments. (Upvoting can of couse be done immediately.)

Comment: @Hendrik, the answer has been normalized. :-)

Comment: @voodoomsr If this really helped you, you should not forget to upvote: It's alway a good way to thank the answerer.

Comment: @xport: Please try and find a good intermediate length. Omitting linebreaks only makes the code obscure.

Comment: @xport: As I said, don't _overdo_ making thinks short. `MyListing` was a much better name for the new environment than `X`.