# \newenvironment fails with special listings environment

Tags: listings, environments

I want to use the `showexpl`, but define a new environment with predefined settings. But all I get is an emergency stop.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RequirePackage{showexpl}
\lstdefinestyle{demoLatexStyle}{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
    numbers=none,               % Ort der Zeilennummern
    frame=none,
}
\begin{document}
\newenvironment{showdemo}[1][]{\LTXexample[style=demoLatexStyle,#1]}{\endLTXexample}

\begin{LTXexample}[style=demoLatexStyle]
\LaTeX{} \LaTeX{}
\end{LTXexample}

\begin{showdemo}    
\LaTeX{} \LaTeX{}
\end{showdemo}

\end{document}
```

> \openout3 = `testdemo.tmp'. Package Listings Warning: Text dropped
>   after begin of listing on input line 24. ! Emergency stop. <*>
>   testdemo.tex
>   *** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

Any hint what I am doing wrong?

Comment: See if the `\lstnewenvironment` command works any better, as shown in [this similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8358/listings-new-environments-with-arguments).

Comment: I think it has to do with there being code within a verbatim environment.

Comment: @Matthias: Does the link Mike linked to solve your problem. If not, please let us know.

Comment: @P. Grill: it uses `\lstnewenvironment` which is not applicable in my case as can also be seen in the comment of the first answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Section 4.16  of [the `listings` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) specifies that to define new environments you need to use the following with syntax similar to LaTeX's `\newenvironment`.

```
\lstnewenvironment
    {<name>}[<number>][<optional default arg>]
    {<starting code>}
    {<ending code>}
```

So, if you replace the `\newenvironment` with the following:

```
\lstnewenvironment{showdemo}[1][]{%
    \lstset{style=demoLatexStyle,#1}}{}%
```

you get the desired result:

[image]

---

**Update**

You could also use `LTXinputExample` and add the necessary code in separate files, or use [the `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents).  Since you asked for an environment below I have defined `showdemoEnv`, but I think the macro version `showdemo` is probably better in this case:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\RequirePackage{showexpl}
\lstdefinestyle{demoLatexStyle}{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily, % Standardschrift
    numbers=none,               % Ort der Zeilennummern
    frame=none,
}

\newcommand{\TempFileName}{\jobname.filecontents.tmp}%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\TempFileName}
\LaTeX{} \LaTeX{}
\end{filecontents*}

\newenvironment{showdemoEnv}[2][]{% Environment version
    \LTXinputExample[style=demoLatexStyle,#1]{#2}%
}{%
  % Add any end environemnt code here.
}%

\newcommand{\showdemo}[2][]{% Macro version
    \LTXinputExample[style=demoLatexStyle,#1]{#2}%
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{LTXexample}[style=demoLatexStyle]
\LaTeX{} \LaTeX{}
\end{LTXexample}

\begin{showdemoEnv}{\TempFileName}    
\end{showdemoEnv}

\showdemo{\TempFileName}
\immediate\write18{rm \TempFileName}% Remove file
\end{document}
```

Note that the starred version `filecontents*` was used. This prevents the header comments that `filecontents` would normally add to the file.

[image]

Comment: Yes I know that command. However what I want is to reuse an environment (in that case `LTExample` of showexpl package) which itsself calls listings. In that case `\lstnewenvironment` can not be applied.

Comment: So it sounds like what you need is something to such as `\lstrenewenvironment` similar to `\renewenvironment`.

Comment: Have updated solution.

Comment: Since I can not delete the created files within LaTeX, I can not consider any solution which is based on the creation of files

Comment: Ok see update where I remove the temp file at end. Have tested this on Mac OS and it works, so it you are using Windows you'll need to see if that command needs to be adapted.